# Averaging different length ranges in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a short macro that includes a line that averages a range of cells. In each worksheet that I want to run the macro in the range of cells is a different length.

After running the macro the cell E1 contains `"=AVERAGE(Rng)"`

```
    Dim homeSheet As Worksheet
    Set homeSheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    Range("E1").Formula = "=Average(Rng)"
    Range("E2").Formula = "=STDEV(Rng)"
    Range("E3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-2
End Sub
```

I've also tried

```
Range("E1").Formula = "=Average(Range("B2:B" & lastRow))"
```

without trying to use `Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Rng.Address` in your formulas. Try to change your code into this:

```
Sub Avg()
    Dim homeSheet As Worksheet
    Set homeSheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    Range("E1").Formula = "=Average(" & Rng.Address & ")"
    Range("E2").Formula = "=STDEV(" & Rng.Address & ")"
    Range("E3").Select
End Sub
```

If you were to use the second method you have tried, you would need to change that line of code to:

```
Range("E1").Formula = "=Average(" & Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Address & ")"
```